# Asterisk - setup hangup after seconds dialplan otpion S(sec)

Tags: asterisk, dialplan

When you dial 876, asterisk pbx start a call, send some dtmf code but doesn't close the call after 2 seconds.
The call need to be closed by the user.

```
[myplan]
exten => _876,1,NoOp(Now should call 207,3 seconds for answer timeout, send DTMF, close the call)
exten => _876,n,Dial(SIP/207,3,D(ww#2334#),S(2))
exten => _876,n,Hangup()
```

From the manual:

> S(x) Hangs up the call x seconds after the called party has answered
> the call.

```
Asterisk 16.13.0
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Thats easy ;-) - Delete the ```,``` between ```D()``` and ```S()``` - Correct it to: ```Dial(SIP/207,3,D(ww#2334#)S(2))```

Comment: ...and: _876 is not a pattern. Use only: 876

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think # mean "wait 1 second" so overal time is over 2 second.
So "S" should work after D ends.

Try following:

```
[myplan]
exten => _876,1,NoOp(Now should call 207,3 seconds for answer timeout, send DTMF, close the call)
exten => _876,n,Set(TIMEOUT(absolute)=2)
exten => _876,n,Dial(SIP/207,3,D(ww#2334#)S(2))
exten => _876,n,Hangup()
```